# Chrome not consoling JS object completely

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am making an AJAX post request with response in JSON.
My ajax code is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "admin/vendors_post.php",
    data: "vendet_req=fetch&venid="+sel_ven,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#trans_loader').css("display", "table");
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

[Consoling the object shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5cXD.png)

[When consoled object is explored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5I6v.png)

The problem is that, the object that I have received in response is not showing some object properties when explored. But when I try to call them explicitly using the dot notation, I get the proper value. I wasted my time looking for those few variables that were not shown when I console the whole response object. For reference, the properties 'id', 'com_name', 'cat_name', etc are not displayed when the console object is explored (refer attached image number 2 above).

What can be the issue? Why the object was not consoled with all properties? I am using jQuery 2.2.0. And using php 5.4.31 on the server side.

NOTE: The object size as per JavaScript is 24, while the actual size, sent from the server, is 29. Though I am able to access those 5 properties explicitly. I am sending data from php post file after 'json_encode()'ing.

Comment: i can see them perfectly fine in the first picture

Comment: Is it possible, that something is transforming your data? This can happen when you log the data to the console, and by the time you expand it, the values will be shown as updated.

Comment: @madalinivascu Yes. I noticed that, but after exploring all properties it just gets disappear.

Comment: @AlexSzabó Thanks. Just found that I had a function call at the end of scope that was transforming few object properties. Thanks by the way. Forgot that the console interprets and shows the updated object when we click on consoled objects.

Comment: @AlexSzabó Put your comment as the answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding my comment here, so it's easier to find from the references:

If there's a data transformation between the `console.log()` and when you expand the items in the console, this can happen.

When the data is logged to the console, it's the state you are after, however if anything changes your data throughout the code, the entry in the browser's console will refer to the updated values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. @Alex is correct. @Yogesh try to avoid that function call and check the console.

Comment: You could have placed that as a comment. I'm aware that you need some reps for that, but I still would advise to use the comment section if you want to place a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing todo with jQuery or PHP, it's how Chrome works.

2 things to notice:

1. In Chrome when you use console.log on an object, it shows only the first **5 properties without sorting them**. When you expand the object, it shows **all the properties sorted alphabetically**.
2. As **@Alex Szabó** said, if the object properties changed after using `console.log()`, the expanded object will display the current properties by the time of expanding.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
```